# Add new activity without menu or action bar in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio 0.8.14 i can't find a way to add new activity without menu.
Android Studio force me to have menu with new activity then if i don't want that menu i must delete it by myself.

Is this a new standard in android that all activities should have an action bar menu? or just somebody forgot to add *real blank activity template* to android studio?

[image: android-studio-new-blank-activity]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android Studio does not have a boilerplate code for an activity without a menu.

HOWEVER,  you can make your own boilplate.  If you look in the folder \plugins\android\lib\templates\activities in your Android Studio installation, you will see templates for everything.  You can easily make your own template, and it will show up in the menu when making a new project.

I'm working on one now for an activity without menu.  I'm almost done, just started in fact when I saw your question.  I would be happy to get it to you after I finish.

EDIT:  Ok I found an even easier way.  In that same folder, you will see a folder called EmptyActivity.  I don't know why it doesn't show in the list of activites when making a project.  However, if you copy and paste that folder into the \plugins\android\lib\templates\activities folder, rename it to whatever you want, then edit the template.xml file to change the name field in  like so:

```
<template
format="3"
revision="4"
name="Blank Activity No Menu Bar"
minApi="7"
minBuildApi="14"
description="Creates a new empty activity">
```

Then it will appear in your list of activities when making a new project.  It will make a new project without a menu, and no action bar.

[image]

Comment: this is good and i'm waiting for your template, but if you see this change as a new standard in android activities what is your answer then?

Comment: Honestly, I think the main reason they included that kind of template rather a blank one is to help people learn where things go.  Personally I would have preferred it had a blank activity from the start.  Oh and see my changes above.

Comment: how can i edit activity template java file ? it still has the onCreateOptionsMenu onOptionsItemSelected onClickMenuOtherActivity methods on it.

Comment: If you copied the folder that says EmptyActivity, the source file (at least on mine) has only 
package ${packageName};

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ${activityClass} extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.${layoutName});
    }
}
in it.  you can edit the file called \root\src\app_package\SimpleActivity.java.ftl with Notepad.